# Summing dice rolls and outputting how many rolls it took to get to that sum in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having a lot of trouble with this one, it keeps giving me partial credit one time I run it and then none the next.
[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LG2OY.png)

Heres the code I have

```
def roll_total(die, total):
    t = die.my_value
    rollnum = 0
    while t < total:
        die.roll
        a = die.my_value
        t += a
        rollnum += 1
    return rollnum
```

Heres the image of the whole code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrs7b.png)

Comment: Shouldn't `t` start out as 0, since the starting value of the die shouldn't already be included in the sum?

Comment: @BeRT2me I have tried it starting at 0, at the initial die value, and at one. The problem lies somewhere else but I can't find it

Comment: My other guess would be `while t <= total:`, but there isn't much to go off of here.

Comment: Can you send the code for the definition of `die`?

Comment: Just updated with the whole file

Comment: Good lord im ignorant. thank you for the help @oda especially and everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `die.roll` by putting parentheses after it: `die.roll()`.